# recursion time complexity calculation

Tags: algorithm, math

Everyone.
I have quick question about one recurrence: T(n) = n^2 * T(n-1).

I am using "recursion-tree method" of CLRS, and got

T(n)=n(square) + (n-1)(square)*n + (n-2)(square)*n*(n-1) + (n-3)(square)*n*(n-1)*(n-2) + ...+1(square)*n!

I don't know how to summarize this expression to a upper bound.
Could some one help here

Comment: Double check: is the `*` in `T(n) = n^2 * T(n-1)` supposed to be a `*` or a `+`?

Comment: Is `CLRS` "Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein"?

Comment: @chux  1. it is *  not + ]   2. u r right, that is what "CLRS" means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating things. If `T(n) = n^2 * T(n - 1)` is correct, you would simply have a product of squares:

[image]

(assuming the stopping condition is n = 1).

Comment: sir, could you tell me how n square * (n-1) square ... * t(1)square    is summarized to  n! square.   many thanks

Comment: @nathan because multiplication is commutative. So if you have two square numbers `a^2 * b^2` you can write them as `(a * b)^2`. It follows that `n^2 * (n - 1)^2 * (n - 2)^2 ...` can be written as `[n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) ...]^2`, and of course `n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) ... ` is defined to be `n!`.

Comment: opps, I can't remember this math. Thanks a lot